# How to get html of div in controller without post method in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am a new user of MVC. Please let me know how to access a div content inside a controller. I am working on SelectPDF. I can not use Post method using ajax.

Is there any way to achieve it by controller.

Thanks

Comment: Please post some code that you may have written. Otherwise it is impossible to decipher what you need help with

Answer (score 0):

A DIV is HTML, for the presentation to the user.
The controller is where the logic is called and the data are pushed to the view (HTML) trough Objects.

You cannot make a div inside a controller!

Otherwise, you can push data from controller to View and then in the View show data in a HTML DIV!